# How to use Meteor.setInterval() with Collection.update() properly

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Hello and sorry for my broken English.

I have a method "updateCounterState" for incrementing and updating a number every second in my mongodb-Collection and showing this number in my template in my html-file. And it seems to work, but I get every time I use this function two errors. For three days I am trying to figure out how to fix these errors. I believe I have to use this code block with a Meteor.bindEnvironment-Wrapper because of my asynchronous updates. However, I don't know how to use this to fix these errors. Or maybe I am completely wrong and these errors have another cause.

**EDIT #2:**

**client/main.html**

```
<head>
  <title>test-timer</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> timeTrackerTemplate}}
</body>

<template name="timeTrackerTemplate">
  {{#each showCounterState}}
    <p class="counter-state">{{state}}</p>
    <button class="start-counting">Start</button>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

**client/main.js**

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';

Template.timeTrackerTemplate.events({
    'click .start-counting': function(e) {
         Meteor.call('updateCounterState', this._id);
    }
});
```

**server/main.js**

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  // code to run on server at startup
});
```

**methods.js (root folder)**

```
Meteor.methods({
    'updateCounterState': function(id) {
        Meteor.setInterval(function() {
            TimeTracker.update(
                {_id: id},
                {
                    $inc: {state: 1},
                },
            );
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

**ttcollection.js (root folder)**

```
TimeTracker = new Mongo.Collection('testtracker');

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.timeTrackerTemplate.helpers({
        showCounterState: function () {
            return TimeTracker.find();
        }
    });
}
```

**meteor:PRIMARY> db.testtracker.find({})**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57ee677227a0af6b59dc12ce"), "state" : 147 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57ee677a27a0af6b59dc12cf"), "state" : 148 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57ee6e6027a0af6b59dc12d0"), "state" : 73 }
```

**Error every time I press a button:**

```
Exception while simulating the effect of invoking 'updateCounterState' Error: Can't set timers inside simulations
    at withoutInvocation (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?hash=ae8b8affa9680bf9720bd8f7fa112f13a62f71c3:463:13)
    at bindAndCatch (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?hash=ae8b8affa9680bf9720bd8f7fa112f13a62f71c3:471:33)
    at Object.setInterval (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?hash=ae8b8affa9680bf9720bd8f7fa112f13a62f71c3:498:24)
    at updateCounterState (http://localhost:3000/app/app.js?hash=f641538433c68c8f8b820f0e05cebb12531cb357:66:20)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?hash=27502404fad7fc072e57e8b0b6719f40d92709c7:3973:25
    at withValue (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?hash=ae8b8affa9680bf9720bd8f7fa112f13a62f71c3:1077:17)
    at Connection.apply (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?hash=27502404fad7fc072e57e8b0b6719f40d92709c7:3964:54)
    at Connection.call (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?hash=27502404fad7fc072e57e8b0b6719f40d92709c7:3840:17)
    at Object.clickStartCounting (http://localhost:3000/app/app.js?hash=f641538433c68c8f8b820f0e05cebb12531cb357:47:20)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=a9372ce320c26570a2e4ec2588d1a6aea57de9c1:3718:20 Error: Can't set timers inside simulations
    at withoutInvocation (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?hash=ae8b8affa9680bf9720bd8f7fa112f13a62f71c3:463:13)
    at bindAndCatch (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?hash=ae8b8affa9680bf9720bd8f7fa112f13a62f71c3:471:33)
    at Object.setInterval (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?hash=ae8b8affa9680bf9720bd8f7fa112f13a62f71c3:498:24)
    at updateCounterState (http://localhost:3000/app/app.js?hash=f641538433c68c8f8b820f0e05cebb12531cb357:66:20)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?hash=27502404fad7fc072e57e8b0b6719f40d92709c7:3973:25
    at withValue (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?hash=ae8b8affa9680bf9720bd8f7fa112f13a62f71c3:1077:17)
    at Connection.apply (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?hash=27502404fad7fc072e57e8b0b6719f40d92709c7:3964:54)
    at Connection.call (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?hash=27502404fad7fc072e57e8b0b6719f40d92709c7:3840:17)
    at Object.clickStartCounting (http://localhost:3000/app/app.js?hash=f641538433c68c8f8b820f0e05cebb12531cb357:47:20)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=a9372ce320c26570a2e4ec2588d1a6aea57de9c1:3718:20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my errors. It is important to call methods with collections on server side only - especially without "insecure" package.

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  //Meteor.methods()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is the `updateCounterState` function defined? Is it a helper on a Template? What are the allow/deny statuses on the TimeTracker collection?

**EDIT** (after question updated)

First, your method takes as a single parameter the id of the TimeTracker, but when you call your method, you don't pass anything. You should either create a TimeTracker object from the client and then pass its `_id`, or take no arguments in your function and create it on the server (in this case, your method should return the `_id` to keep track of it.

Then, putting code in the root folder is not the best practice, you should use the `/imports` folder and then `import { foo } from 'foo.js'`, or put your code in `/server` or `/client`.

Your Template helpers returns a Mongo cursor which is of no use. If you want to return a single TimeTracker, use `TimeTracker.findOne({ _id: id })` which will return the object. Basically, you should probably have something like:

```
Template.timeTrackerTemplate.onCreated(function () {
  this.trackerId = null;
});

Template.timeTrackerTemplate.helpers({
  showCounterState: function() {
    const trackerId = Template.instance().trackerId;
    return trackerId ? TimeTracker.findOne({ _id: trackerId }).state : ''; 
  }
});

Template.timeTrackerTemplate.events({
  'click .start-counting': function(e, instance) {
    instance.trackerId = TimeTracker.insert({ state: 0 });
     Meteor.call('updateCounterState', instance.trackerId);
  }
});
```

Comment: Hello. I added more code. I have no allow/deny on my collection. I placed my collection in the root folder  - so that client and server have both access to this collection. But my client have to use my method to update my document. I removed meteor's "insecure" packages, but these errors still exists.

Comment: Hello again and thank your for your patience! I created a new project and I want to keep this example as simple as possible - without extra folders like /imports or extra templates. I believe this error has nothing to do with my folder structure or am I wrong? I updated my code again - this time with complete code and mongo-db entries. Everything works, but I get this error every time I press my buttons. Can you please look again over my code? Thank you!